# Python argparse ignoring defualt values

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to use the `defualt` argument for argparse, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

predictor_path = r"C:\Noam\Code\vision_course\shape_predictor\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
assert os.path.isfile(predictor_path)
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor",
                required=True,
                default=predictor_path,
                help="path to facial landmark predictor",
                nargs='?',
                )
image_path = r"C:\Noam\Code\vision_course\face_pose_estimation\images\valid_set\images\image_00008.png"
assert os.path.isfile(image_path)
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image",
                required=True,
                default=image_path,
                help="path to input image",
                nargs='?',
                )
```

Gives the following error, when called with no command line arguments:

> error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor, -i/--image

Since I provided a default value, I expected this to work with no arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have `required=True` for both arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the default value to be used when the option is not specified, then drop the `required=True`. Because you have included `required=True` you are saying that the option *must appear on the command line*.